# Python: Omitting Content inside Capturing Regexes

Tags: python, regex

I am working on capturing a subset of abbreviations using regular expressions in Python 2.x. Several such abbreviation appears in the following text:

```
# text                                    # desired capture
The certolizumab pegol (Cmzia, CZP)...      'CZP'
The drug 6-mercatopureine (6-mp) ...        '6-mp'
The merits of 5-Asasdfdsf (5-ASA) ...       '5-ASA'
```

In the first example, I am interested in getting the result back `CZP` and ignoring the `Cmzia,`.

Here's the prior regular expression I had, which is necessary for matching cases like `(6-mp)` and `(5-ASA)`:

```
\((\S*[A-Z-0-9]\S*)\)  # captures '6-mp' and '5-ASA', respectively
```

Here's the addition I made to handle the above case:

```
\S*\s+[A-Z-0-9]+  # I only want to capture the '[A-Z-0-9]+'
```

I have tried using the following regular expressions (I attempted to bold the portion of interest, so that it wouldn't get confused with the context, but that didn't seem to work):

```
# in p1, I add the pattern to the list, separated by '|'
>>> p1 = re.compile(r'\((\S*[A-Z-0-9]\S*|\S*\s+[A-Z-0-9]+)\)')
>>> p1.findall('The certolizumab pegol (Cmzia, CZP)')
['Cmzia, CZP']

# in p2, I use a broad non-capturing group, enclosing the desired captured expressions in parentheses
>>> p2 = re.compile(r'\((?:(\S*[A-Z-0-9]\S*)|\S*\s+([A-Z-0-9]+))\)')
>>> p2.findall('The certolizumab pegol (Cmzia, CZP)')                           
[('', '', 'CZP')] 

# this is an addition to the original post
# demonstrates that the non-capturing expression doesn't prevent capture of the section \S*\s+
>>> p3 = re.compile(r'\((\S*[A-Z-0-9]\S*|(?:\S*\s+)[A-Z-0-9]+)\)')
>>> p3.findall('The certolizumab pegol (Cmzia, CZP)')                           
['Cmzia, CZP']
```

Ideally, I want the output `CZP`. *p1* returns too much, as I want to exclude the `\S*\s+` corresponding to `Cmzia,`.  With respect to *p2*, I know I can easily manipulate the output to match my desired output, but I would like to know if there's a way to modify the regex to handle it.

Thanks, and let me know if you need additional details/clarification.

**Edit:**

I still want the regular expression to capture the `6-mp` and `5-ASA` from the first/original part of the regex.

**Edit 2:**

This is included above, but to put it in one location and summarize my question.

```
pattern = r'???'
p = re.compile(pattern)
p.findall('Stuff stuff (Cmzia, CZP) stuff stuff (5-ASA) (6-mp) stuff...')
['CZP','5-ASA','6-mp']
```

Comment: Please give your input and expected output. When you say original post, I don't know what you are talking out without any references.

Comment: @Pogo: Expected input and output is included. "This is an addition to the original post" means that I have added this to clarify a comment/answer.

Comment: @Pogo: I've also added another edit to clarify exactly what I'm interested in.

Comment: Just for clarification, what should be returned from "Stuff stuff (penguin, CZP, hovercraft)"?

Comment: @che: Nothing should be returned: it's not an expected pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the simplest regex I've found to achieve your goal:

```
>>> p = "\((?:\S*,\s+)?(\S*)\)"
>>> s = "The cert pegol (Cmzia, CZP) some words (6-mp) and (5-ASA)"
>>> re.findall(p,s)
['CZP', '6-mp', '5-ASA']
```

**Update**

The next one is more restrictive but it gives the same result:

```
>>> p = "\((?:\S*,\s+)?(\S*[A-Z-0-9]\S*)\)"
```

Comment: Yes, that's the output I want, though I was interested in finding a way to modify the regular expression rather than the result returned by the regular expression. The primary difference is that in your solution, I have to hard-code the number of possible cases beforehand. If I modify the regex again (add another pattern), I have to change each `[x or y for (x, y) in l]`. Sure, I could apply this as a function call, but I'd still rather just fix the regex. Perhaps this isn't possible?

Comment: I did one more update today. I think both proposals in the answer fit your needs now.

Comment: Yes, both correctly satisfy the question (although the first is not restrictive enough). Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand what you want, but I have added another matching parentheses around the part corresponding to 'CZP' and made the outer group non-matching, and got this:

```
>>> p3 = re.compile(r'\((?:\S*[A-Z-0-9]\S*|[A-Z-0-9]* [A-Z-0-9]*|(?:\S*\s+)([A-Z-0-9]+))\)')
>>> p3.findall('The certolizumab pegol (Cmzia, CZP)')
['CZP']
```

Comment: I'm afraid I didn't explain myself particularly well. The other portions of the regular expression already match certain patterns, and return results. For instance, `\S*[A-Z-0-9]\S*` matches the text '(6-mp)' and returns '6-mp'. In other words, I am interested in making the original regex more robust.

Comment: I'm afraid I still fail to see the pattern you want to get out of this. If I have some part in the parentheses, you only want to return the part after the last comma?

Comment: @DavidC - It would probably be easier to assist if you just gave several examples of strings and the expected results. Then people can cater the solutions to your specific needs.

Comment: @JamesSwift: I have included all the desired outputs for both cases. '6-mp' captured from '(6-mp)', '5-ASA' captured from '(5-ASA)', and 'CZP' from '(Cmzia, CZP)'. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: @DavidC - I think it just wasn't clear that these were 3 separate cases and that the first 2 would be by themselves whereas the CZP would have another item included in the parenthesis. I submitted an edit for the question, let me know if it is not what you intended.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading you correctly, there can be one or two comma-separated values inside the parentheses.  If it's two, you only want to capture the second one.  Try this:

```
p = re.compile(r'\((?:[^,)]+,\s*)?([A-Za-z0-9-]+)\)')
```

After the opening paren, `(?:[^,)]+,\s*)?` tries to match the first value, which it identifies by the presence of a the trailing comma.  You don't really care what the first value looks like, as long as there aren't any commas in it.  But you can't use just `[^,]+` because that would match too much in cases where there's only one value.  Adding the paren to the list of excluded characters keeps the match contained within the one set of parentheses.